# How to remove an OverlayEntry from an Overlay?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm simply trying to remove an `OverlayEntry` that I inserted into an `Overlay` earlier:

```
rootOverlay.insert(entry);
```

I can't seem to find a method that does that though.
I did find a private method `_remove`in the `OverlayState` class, but I can not access that.

Am I missing something? How would you do that in Flutter?

Answer (score 12):

The remove method is not inside `OverlayState` but the `OverlayEntry` itself

```
entry.remove()
```

Comment: Oh wow, another day, another answer by Rémi!
But this seems a bit weird to me, why is it implemented like this?

Comment: I don't have the "why ?". But I find this pretty clever actually. You always need to keep your overlay entry somewhere, to use `marksNeedsBuild` anyway.

Comment: Ah in the end I think I know. It's because in many situation you'll need to remove the overlay inside `dispose` method. The thing is, you usually can't call `of(context)` inside dispose.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: Also you might have more than one and want to specify which one to remove.  But still, I can remove the overlay using a button, but not from dispose.